# KeyChain Access for Macbook Pro and GitHub

Tags: git, macos, github

GitHub is now moving to not using passwords to connect to repositories. I am wondering how this works with Git on Macs because it stores your username and password for access in the Keychain.

I currently use ssh to do my Git work, however, I have come across problems with using Mac's package manager, Homebrew.

Does anyone know a different Git credential helper I could use or some other solution?
Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you use HTTPS with Git on a Mac to access GitHub, then you can continue to do so, just with a personal access token instead of a password.  This personal access token is sent over the HTTP protocol just like a password would be.  The main differences between using a personal access token and a password are the following:

- The personal access token is generated by a CSPRNG, so it is computationally infeasible for anyone to guess.  While users can often pick weak passwords, personal access tokens will never be duplicated across users and will never be weak.
- Personal access tokens can be restricted with scopes to perform only certain activities, unlike passwords.  As a consequence, if a PAT is accidentally exposed, the damage is more limited and it can be easily revoked and replaced.

To use a PAT with the Git, you can [reset the credentials used in your credential manager](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitfaq#http-reset-credentials) by doing this:

```
$ echo url=https://github.com | git credential reject
```

Then, next time that Git prompts you for a username and password to access GitHub, enter your username as normal, then generate a PAT with the `repo` scope and paste it in as your password.  If you're using a credential manager, which is the default configuration on macOS, from then on, Git will use those credentials to access GitHub.